# How to execute multiple queries in one call in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I'm running prometheus inside kubernetes cluster.

I need to send queries to Prometheus every minute, to gather information of many metrics from many containers. There are too match queries, so I must combine them.

I know how I can ask Prometheus for one metric information on multiple containers: `my_metric{container_name=~"frontend|backend|db"}` , but I haven't found a way to ask Prometheus for multiple metric information in one query.

I'm looking for the equivalent to 'union' in sql queries.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I found [here](https://www.robustperception.io/whats-in-a-__name__/) this solution: `{__name__=~"metricA|metricB|metricC",container_name=~"frontend|backend|db"}`.

Comment: The article you link to specifically says that using regex on `__name__` is an antipattern.

Comment: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/ states no qualms against this construct.

Comment: The linked article says that its example regex with wildcards "is an anti-pattern, as you're meant to know your metric names a-priori." I think the spirit of this question and answer is that you _do_ know the exact names of the metrics you want (that is, you're not using any wild cards in your regex) you just want more than one at a time. To me, this answer doesn't seem to fit into the anti-pattern they're worried about.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `or` operator, however this does not generalise as it ignores metric names. I'd suggest making multiple queries to the API.

Comment: Thanks, easiest and most elegant solution for quickly debugging a query in Prometheus' query tool.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus provides [`or` operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators), which can be used for combining results from multiple queries in a single API call. For example, the following query returns results for `q1`, `q2` and `q3`:

```
q1 or q2 or q3
```

The `or` operator in PromQL has a quirk though - if some time series returned by `q1`, `q2` and `q3` have the same set of labels (excluding metric name aka `__name__` label), then only the first encountered time series is returned. For example, the following query returns only `process_cpu_seconds_total` time series, and doesn't return `process_resident_memory_bytes` time series, since they have the same set of labels except of metric name:

```
process_cpu_seconds_total or process_resident_memory_bytes
```

This can be fixed by copying the metric name into another label. For example, the following query copies the metric name into `metric_name` label, so the `or` result contains time series from both `process_cpu_seconds_total` and `process_resident_memory_bytes` sides:

```
label_join(process_cpu_seconds_total, "metric_name", "", "__name__")
  or
label_join(process_resident_memory_bytes, "metric_name", "", "__name__")
```

P.S. There is a simpler solution for obtaining results from multiple queries in one call if using an alternative Prometheus-like monitoring system I work on - [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics) - it provides [union](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#union) function for this task. For example, the following query returns time series for both `process_cpu_seconds_total` and `process_resident_memory_bytes` queries:

```
union(
  process_cpu_seconds_total,
  process_resident_memory_bytes,
)
```