# Merge/join two metrics in Prometheus/PromQL

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have two different (but related metrics).

```
metric_1(id="abc",id2="def")
metric_2(id="abc",id2="def")
```

My goal ultimately is to have the following in Grafana. I plan to use the "instant" value and Grafana's table visualization widget to display this data.

```
id      id2     metric1 metric2
abc     def     1       2
```

What query/joining/relabeling should I use to achieve this?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 14):

```
{__name__=~"metric_1|metric_2"}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47415934/661150
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can append `+ 0` to the query so that Prometheus strips out its `__name__` label so Grafana will merge them together. I found this workaround on [GitHub](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/10050#issuecomment-393207206).

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that in Grafana

- make two queries, be sure to select format `table`
- merge them with `transform` => `merge`
- relable and hide unwanted fields with `organize fields`

Answer (score 1):

A bit of changes which merges all the steps before. The solution can be achieved in Grafana

1. Make 2 queries and select visualization format as table
2. Apply transformation Labels to fields (Select value filed name a value that uniquely identifies the metric name e.g. **name**)
3. Merge them together transform ==> merge
4. Reorganize/rename the field names